# sharepoint autohosted app aspects

Tags: sharepoint, azure, office365, sharepoint-2013

I recently started to develop apps for SharePoint 2013. Apps are auto-hosted and my question is what exactly mean that apps are auto-hosted.

I know that components are working not on SharePoint, but in external device. In windows azure cloud in this case.(auto-hosted), but my question is how windows azure account is connected to office365 account? Because I can deploy SharePoint 2013 app to Office 365 without any windows azure credentials.

So my question is which windows azure account is used?

Answer (score 0):

The account is entirely handled by Microsoft: you could even ignore about its existence (but you can use some Azure's features, though).

For information about the features available with each plan, please refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj819267.aspx.

For information about boundaries and limits of each Subscription level, you can refer to http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/sharepoint-online-software-boundaries-and-limits-HA102694293.aspx.

Best regards,
Simone